# Can't call non-static member function from imported class c++

Tags: c++, non-static

My problem is with the line memory.initBoard(); I've instantiated an instance of memory with a constructor, which resolves fine. once I try to call a member function using the dot-notation, I get an error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Board::initBoard()", referenced from:
      _main in ccpQWFDT.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I've tried removing the Board:: before initBoard in the .cpp file but that did not work. Anyone have any idea why I can't call this member function?

This is the main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Board.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
Board memory(8);
memory.initBoard();
return 0;
}
```

This is the .h file

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H
#include <vector>

class Board {
   private:
       Board(){}
   public:
      int board_size;
      Board(int size);
      void initBoard();
 };
#endif
```

This is the .cpp that goes with the .h file

```
#include "Board.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Board::Board(int size) {

}
inline void Board::initBoard(){

}
```

Comment: Are you compiling and linking both cpp files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `inline` from the function definition. That makes it usable in `Board.cpp` only.

Comment: or move the function to `.h` file if really want `inline`